# WP query with multiple custom meta not respecting orderby

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have created a wp query to pull a series of posts that have one of three categories (current, upcoming, or past) and I used the multiple custom meta array technique as I want the posts to display in the order of current followed by upcoming, and then past.

However, every time I include past posts, they override the upcoming posts and appear directly after the post marked as current.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Here is my query:

```
      $args = array(
                    'post_type'      => 'event',
                    'posts_per_page' => '4',
                    'publish_status' => 'published',
                    'meta_query'  => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'currentarray' => array(
                        'key'       => 'event_category',
                        'value'     => 'current',
                        'compare' => '=',   
                        ),
                        'upcomingarray' => array(
                        'key'       => 'event_category',
                        'value'     => 'upcoming',
                        'compare' => '=',
                        ),
                        'pastarray' => array(
                        'key'       => 'event_category',
                        'value'     => 'past',
                        'compare' => '=',   
                        ),
                    )
                ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'currentarray'   => 'ASC',
        'upcomingarray'  => 'ASC',
        'pastarray'     => 'ASC',
    ),        

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: when you said you include past posts, can you be specific about what you meant and how you did it? Also can you fix the incorrect indenting in your code so it's easier to read? You've specified what to order by but it sounds like you actually wanted a group by, not an order by. Think of it this way, you've told it to order the posts by their "currentness", and if 2 posts have equal current values use their "upcoming" value and then "past" value, but all or the current posts have the same value "current", and all the upcoming have the same value etc

Comment: there's a custom field called event_category with one of three values - current, upcoming, or past. That's what I'm including in the meta query array. I want to display each category in the order I'm specifying, which is why I'm doing it this way. If I wasn't, I'd be using something like 'value' => array('past','upcoming','current')

Comment: I don't think what you want can be achieved this way, you're trying to group all the `past` together then all the `upcoming` together, followed finally by `current`, which isn't something you can do. You can prioritise what it sorts by but it will sort within that clause which isn't what you're trying to do. What you want almost certainly requires custom filters for the SQL groupby clause.

Comment: also `'publish_status' => 'published',` doesn't make much sense and would be stripped out by `WP_Query` and ignored, `'post_status' => 'publish'` is what you want. Likewise `'posts_per_page' => '4',` should strictly be `'posts_per_page' => 4,`. I can see what you were trying to do with clauses but that's not how they work. Clauses can let you use meta to sort, but you can't use them to sort the same key as a pseudo-group by like this